# os_log messages not showing for archived catalyst application

Tags: swift, macos, mac-catalyst

I am using a Wrapper in a personal Swift package to use `os_log` to print log messages to console:

```swift
import Foundation
import os

public class ATLogger {

    public static let shared = ATLogger()

    public func logToConsole(file: String = #file, function: String = #function, line: Int = #line, message: String, type: OSLogType) {
        let osLog: OSLog
        if let subsystem = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier {
            osLog = OSLog(subsystem: subsystem, category: "Appfrosch")
        } else {
            osLog = .default
        }
        let file = String(file.split(separator: "/").last ?? "")

        os_log("*** %{public}s/%{public}s, line %d -- %s", log: osLog, type: type, file, function, line, message)
    }
}
```

I then call it where I see it fit, e.g. in my SceneDelegate to log the start of the app like so:

```swift
ATLogger.shared.logToConsole(message: "Application started", type: .default)
```

This works fine when running the catalyst version of the applications from Xcode on macOS for all log levels – i.e. all messages are visible on the Console (I have Debug and Info activated):

[image]

My problem is that when I make an artefact of said application by archiving and then copy it to my system, the so started application does *not* show these same messages on Console.

`sudo log stream --level default | grep Appfrosch` gives the same result: the applications logs successfully when run from Xcode, but not when run as an artefact.

What might I be missing?

Comment: With your code, with Xcode 11.4.1 works fine in Xcode and in local.

Comment: Haven't had the time to look into this the past weeks – but it seems that you are right: works on my machine now as well with Xcode 11.4.1. So maybe it's just been an Xcode issue after all...